# An error occurred please try again later playback id, go to next video?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, playback

I have a simple Youtube API code to play videos in a playlist. All of a sudden I start getting the error like: an error occurred please try again later playback id: 2yVtrSo5yT1rs1EY

I did some searching and mainly found solutions for the PC user, like flushing cache/dns etc (I am on a windows laptop by the way).

**Question:** I was wondering however if it is possible to create a solution for this error(code), in the script in order to make it go to the next song? Or is this only a user based problem? I have an `onPlayerError` function that just makes the player go to the next song, whatever error occurs. However for the error mentioned above, it does nothing and just shows the error.

```
<?php
$yt_id='PLFgquLnL59anYA8FwzqNFMp3KMcbKwMaT';
$mymaxcounter = 100;                                    
?>

<div id="player"></div>
<script>
        // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
        var tag = document.createElement('script');

        tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        var player;
        var numPl = Math.floor((Math.random() * <?php echo $mymaxcounter;?>) + 1);
        var playlistId = "<?php echo $yt_id; ?>";
        // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)        
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player("player", {
                height: '390',
                width: '640',
        playerVars: {
                autoplay: 1,
                loop: 1
                },
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onError': onPlayerError
                }
            });
        }
        // onPlayerReady
        function onPlayerReady(event){
        //More player vars
        player.loadPlaylist( {
                listType: 'playlist',
                list: playlistId,
                index: numPl
    } );

        //Set shuffle   
        setTimeout(function() {
                player.setShuffle({'shufflePlaylist' : true});
              }, 1000);
            }

        // onPlayerError
        function onPlayerError(){
            player.nextVideo();
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Please try add `https:` to the following line: ` tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";`. I made a local .html file and your code works as expected *(if the iframe finds a problematic video), it just search for another playable video*. I couldn't make it work on jsfiddle neither in Stack Overflow due to its restrictions for using iframe. It would be helpful if I post an answer with the modifications I made?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. I just found the problem. Had to do with a playlist containing less videos than the amount defined by $mymaxcounter variable. Thus a video is loaded that does not exist. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: RobbTe, I'm glad you found the root of the problem. You can answer your own question too and so you will help other members of Stack Overflow. Also, remember accept it. Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer